# Multipart ajax request to servlet - request.getParameter() returning null

Tags: html, servlets, request, multipartform-data, ajaxform

I am submitting a request via Ajax, but whenever i am sending the multi-part request request.getParameter is always returning null. without multi-part request its working

JS Code

```
$scope.saveProduct = function () {
    var urlForCreateProduct = getUrl("create_product");
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', $('#product_image')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('product_title',$scope.Product.product_title);
    formData.append('product_desc',$scope.Product.product_desc);
    formData.append('product_details',$scope.Product.product_details);
    formData.append('product_price',$scope.Product.product_price);
    formData.append('product_category',$scope.Product.product_category);
    formData.append('product_id',getUniqueID() + "");

    $.ajax({
        url: urlForCreateProduct,
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            if(response.status && response.status == "success"){
                toastr.success('Product Created!');
                $('#addProductModel').modal('hide');
            } else {
                /* error */
                toastr.error(response.message);
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            /* error */
            toastr.error(error.message);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Why you don't use JSON to send this data.
It the easy way from me. 
Whit JSON you can use JSON data type for sending.

Comment: If possible try to use jquery-form plugin which will enable you do directly submit form with action and that is also using ajax only. you don't need to worry about getting data ans setting it to a variable and adding that variable to the form data.

Comment: Thanks @DenisKohl, Used JSON